# What is the mechanism that allows Python monkey patching in this instance?

Tags: python, global-variables, monkeypatching, python-internals, side-effects

Can someone explain the logic behind how this works with the Python interpreter? Is this behavior only thread local? Why does the assignment in the first module import persist after the second module import? I just had a long debugging session that came down to this.

*external_library.py*

```
def the_best():
    print "The best!"
```

*modify_external_library.py*

```
import external_library

def the_best_2():
    print "The best 2!"

external_library.the_best = the_best_2
```

*main.py*

```
import modify_external_library

import external_library

external_library.the_best()
```

Test:

```
$ python main.py
The best 2!
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nothing thread-local about this.  `somemodule.anattr = avalue` is **very** global behavior!  After this assignment the attribute is changed for good (until maybe changed back later) no matter what.

There's no mysterious mechanics at play!  Assignment to any attribute of an object that allows such assignment (as module objects do) just work in the obvious way -- no thread-local anything, nothing strange -- and assignment to attribute persists, as long as the object whose attribute you've assigned persists, of course.

The repeated `import external_library` doesn't **reload** the module (`reload` is a totally separate builtin and `import` does **not** call it!) -- it just checks `sys.modules`, finds an `external_library` key in that `dict`, and binds the corresponding value (which was previously modified by that assignment) to name `external_library` in the appropriate namespace (here, globals of module `main`).

Comment: Thanks, I've used the `reload` builtin before, but only to re-import within the same module. Knowing about `sys.modules` makes this make a lot more sense.

Comment: This no longer works in Python 3

Answer (score 2):

Modules are instances of new-style classes. When you modify the attributes of a module (the function in this case), you are modifying the module instance. When you try to import it again (with `import external_library`), you're just getting the same module object already referenced inside of `modify_external_library.py`.

**Edit**: Of course, *trying* to import the same module again does not really work (as Alex Martelli points out). Once loaded, modules are not re-initialized unless done so explicitly with `reload`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out how this is affected by new-style classes.

Answer (score 1):

As Alex indicated you need to reload `external_library`, simply importing it will do nothing if it's already been imported. You can check that by putting `print` statements into your `external_library` and `modify_external_library` modules.

```
import modify_external_library

#import external_library
reload(external_library)

external_library.the_best()
```

**output**

```
The best!
```

Answer (score 0):

Monkey patching works because classes are modifiable in python but the mechanism that allows it to spread like this is that once any module has been imported, and initialised, later imports simply add the existing instance to the local namespace without rerunning the initialisation, this also saves time when a module has a lot of initialisation as well as allowing monkey patches.